# Performing aggregation using meteor-mongo-extensions

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've installed the mongodb-aggregation package but I get "undefined" returned when peforming an aggregation within a meteor method. I assume that I'm missing something fundamental. How should the aggregation be performed? Any advice would be great.

```
rate: function(ratingProp){
    var user = Meteor.user();
    var postId = ratingProp.postId;
    var post = Posts.findOne({_id: postId});
    var rateVal = ratingProp.rateVal;


    // ensure the user is logged in
    if (!user) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to signin to rate.");
    }

    // ensure rating has rateVal
    if (!rateVal){
        throw new Meteor.Error(422, "No rating provided.");
    }

    // ensure rating has a post
    if (!post){
        throw new Meteor.Error(422, "Rating not associated with a post.");
    }

    Ratings.upsert({userId: user._id, postId: postId}, 
                    {$set: { rateVal: rateVal }}
    );

    // perform aggregation
    var avgRate = Ratings.aggregate([
        {$match:
            // hard coded for testing
            {postId: "D7f3WoDEGW3SqGKW9"}
        },
        {$group:
            {
                _id: null,
                "avgRating":{$avg: "$rateVal"}
            }
        }
    ]);


   // additional code...
```

Answer (score 2):

Most importantly, note that `db.ratings.aggregate` has not a thing to do with meteor or meteor-mongo-extensions . **Mongo** itself has a native `db.<collection>.aggregate()` function. So thats why it works in the shell.

Now for  **Meteor**. Meteor uses a custom mongo driver so it can set up all the nice reactive aspects in Meteor.Collection(), among other things. As such, some of the mongo functions have not yet been implemented.

And finally **meteor-mongo-extensions**, that is effectively a hack of a hack. I have yet to confirm it I believe the issue can be found in this [Github issue](https://github.com/jhoxray/meteor-mongo-extensions/issues/6). Try to run this on the server outside the meteor method, just to be sure.

If your issue is that the package is broken you can try one of the many packages on Atmosphere that manage aggregation. mongodb-server-aggregation looks promising.

Comment: Thanks! I still receive undefined after moving the aggregation outside the method. Which packages support aggregation? I was only able to find mongodb-aggregation (the one I was using) and mongodb-server-aggregation on atmosphere.

Comment: Given your example mongodb-server-aggregation is the one I would try. You can wrap the call inside of a meteor method, like in your example, and it should work just fine. Do understand that this functionality should eventually be added to core Meteor collections. Everything until then will just be a patch. (Let me know if this fixed it for you, thanks!)

Comment: I tried mongodb-server-aggregation, but had the same undefined issue. I've got a hack in place where I maintain a sum and count and calculate an average, but it is probably susceptible to a race condition. I will try going back to mongodb-server-aggregation when I finish up some of the other things I'm working on and see if I can resolve the issue.

Comment: Little late to answer, but I'm having different results between mongo shell and aggregation packages on atmosphere. It's quite frustating.